# How to add "<" to Back button?

Tags: ios, ios7

When implementation an action for a navigation controller's back button, the "<" character is removed.  I'd like the back button to look exactly like the original back button.  The only issue seems to be how to get the "<" to appear?

```
UIBarButtonItem *item = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered  target:self action:@selector(goback:)];
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = item;
```

Is there some way to do that?

Also, is `self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;` needed?

Ultimately, I just want to know the button was clicked.  I haven't found a way to do that without creating a new button, which of course overrides the existing back button style.  It doesn't seem apple provides a UIBarButtonItemStyle for the back button.

Answer (score 0):

If you inspect the view hierarchy of a system back button, it's just an image and a button. You could recreate the same effect by creating a bar button item with a custom view that contains an image view with the `<` image and a button.

`hidesBackButton` is not necessary when you set a left bar button item.

Comment: I don't think that will work.  If you look at the Back button animation, the "<" and text appear to be different items.  The "<" is static on the left and the "Back" slides in from the right.

Comment: If you want to have the animation, use a normal back button item. Why are you overriding it in the first place? You can set the `backBarButtonItem` to override the text, and it will use the native animation.

Comment: "Why are you overriding it in the first place?" Because I need to know it was clicked. Is there a better way to accomplish that?  Where do you set backBarButtonItem?